# How to design HBase schema for Twitter data?

Tags: twitter, nosql, hbase

I have following Twitter data and I want to design a schema for the same .The queries which I would need to perform would be following:
get tweets volume for time interval,tweets with corresponding user info,tweets with corresponding topic info etc... Based on the below data ,anyone tell where designing of schema is correct.. (make rowkey as id+timestamp, column family as user ,others grouped into primary column . Any Suggestions ?

```
{
   "created_at":"Tue Feb 19 11:16:34 +0000 2013",
   "id":303825398179979265,
   "id_str":"303825398179979265",
   "text":"Unleashing Innovation Conference Kicks Off - Wall Street Journal (India)              http:\/\/t.co\/3bkXJBz1",
   "source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/dlvr.it\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003edlvr.it\u003c\/a\u003e",
   "truncated":false,
   "in_reply_to_status_id":null,
   "in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,
   "in_reply_to_user_id":null,
   "in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,
   "in_reply_to_screen_name":null,
   "user":{
      "id":948385189,
      "id_str":"948385189",
      "name":"Innovation Plaza",
      "screen_name":"InnovationPlaza",
      "location":"",
      "url":"http:\/\/tinyurl.com\/ee4jiralp",
      "description":"All the latest breaking news about Innovation",
      "protected":false,
      "followers_count":136,
      "friends_count":1489,
      "listed_count":1,
      "created_at":"Wed Nov 14 19:49:18 +0000 2012",
      "favourites_count":0,
      "utc_offset":28800,
      "time_zone":"Beijing",
      "geo_enabled":false,
      "verified":false,
      "statuses_count":149,
      "lang":"en",
      "contributors_enabled":false,
      "is_translator":false,
      "profile_background_color":"131516",
      "profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/781710342\/17a75bf22d9fdad38eebc1c0cd441527.jpeg",
      "profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/781710342\/17a75bf22d9fdad38eebc1c0cd441527.jpeg",
      "profile_background_tile":true,
      "profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/3205718892\/8126617ac6b7a0e80fe219327c573852_normal.jpeg",
      "profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/3205718892\/8126617ac6b7a0e80fe219327c573852_normal.jpeg",
      "profile_link_color":"009999",
      "profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF",
      "profile_sidebar_fill_color":"EFEFEF",
      "profile_text_color":"333333",
      "profile_use_background_image":true,
      "default_profile":false,
      "default_profile_image":false,
      "following":null,
      "follow_request_sent":null,
      "notifications":null
   },
   "geo":null,
   "coordinates":null,
   "place":null,
   "contributors":null,
   "retweet_count":0,
   "entities":{
      "hashtags":[

      ],
      "urls":[
         {
            "url":"http:\/\/t.co\/3bkXJBz1",
            "expanded_url":"http:\/\/dlvr.it\/2yyG5C",
            "display_url":"dlvr.it\/2yyG5C",
            "indices":[
               73,
               93
            ]
         }
      ],
      "user_mentions":[

      ]
   },
   "favorited":false,
   "retweeted":false,
   "possibly_sensitive":false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% sure that the ID is unique, you could this one as your row key to store the bulk of the data:

303825398179979265 -> data_CF

You column family data_CF would be defined in these lines:

```
"created_at":"Tue Feb 19 11:16:34 +0000 2013"
"id_str":"303825398179979265"
...
"user_id":948385189 { take note here I'm denormalizing your dictionary }
"user_name":"Innovation Plaza"
```

It gets a little trickier for the lists. The solution is to put something that will make it unique prefixed by the category:

```
"entities_hashtags_":"\x00" { Here \x00 is a dummy value }
```

For the URL, if the ordering is not important, you may prefix it with a UUID. It will guarantee that it is unique.

The advantage with this approach is if you need to update a field in this data, it will be done atomically since HBase guarantees row atomicity.

For the second question, if you need instantaneous aggregated information, you will have to precompute it and store it as you said in another table. If you want this data to be generated through M/R, you may put the timestamp + row id if it is to be time based. By topic would be something like topic + row id. This allows you to write Prefix scans with start stop row that will include only the time range or the topic you are interested.

Have fun !